# Network version of central limit theorem?

Tags: time-series, probability, central-limit-theorem

Is there a version of the central limit theorem for random variables that are connected through a network? More precisely, imagine I have $N$ vertices in a graph, and a random variable $X_{i}$ for every $i \in \{1,...,N\}$. The random variable is given by

$$X_i = \sum_{j=1}^{N} \alpha_{ij} X_j + \epsilon_i$$
where

1. $\epsilon_i$ are i.i.d with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$
2. $\alpha_{ij} \geq 0$ for all $i,j$
3. $\lim_{N \to \infty} \max_{j \leq N} \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_{ij} < 1$
4. $\lim_{N \to \infty} \max_{i \leq N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} \alpha_{ij} < 1$

I know from the above assumptions that $L = (I-\alpha)^{-1}$ exists, that $X = L \epsilon$, and that $\mu_i =_{def} \mathbb{E}[X_i]= \sum_{j=1}^N L_{ij} \mu$ and $\sigma_i^2 =_{def} Var(X_i) = \sum_{j=1}^N L_{ij}^2 \sigma^2$. However, the variables $X_1,...,X_N$ are correlated, so the standard central limit does not apply. Is there an assumption under which we can prove something of the form

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{j=1}^N (X_j - \mu_j) = N(0,J) $$
for some $J$?

I'm aware this can be done for time series (e.g. $\alpha_{ij} = \rho < 1$ for $j = i-1$, $\alpha_{ij} = 0$ for all other cases), but I'm wondering if it can be done for network defined random variables, where $X_i$ may depend on $X_{i+1},X_{i+2},...$.

Comment: How does the topology of the graph vary with $N$ and how does the sum reflect anything about the graph at all?? At any rate, you need stronger conditions on the $\alpha_{ij}$ to prevent a finite number of the $X_i$ from contributing too much to the sums.

Comment: Thanks. One assumption I could make is that $\alpha_{ij} = \gamma_{j-i \mod N}$ for all $j$ such that $i-k \leq j \leq i+k$, and $\alpha_{ij} = 0$  for $j$ such that $j < i -k$ or $j > i+k$. This would give something like an AR(k) process, except  $X_{ij}$ would not only  depend on $X_{i,j-1},....,X_{i,j-k}$, but also on $X_{i,j+1},...,X_{i,j+k}$.